# UFT(Unified Functional Testing) tool object identification is different in two different machines

Tags: vbscript, qtp, hp-uft

I am automating the setup screen of one product which was developed in .Net. When I was spying the setup dialog in one machine it was identified as `SWFObject` and another machine it was identified as `WinObject`. Not sure how to overcome this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you've activated the .NET add-on in the add-on manager (on the second machine) and that the application is included in the **Record and Run Settings**.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Motti. I have checked all my add on information (.NET addon present)and Record and Run Settings but still UFT identifying in two different ways.

Comment: You should also verify that the application is launched after UFT.